# Is it possible to override the automated assignment of uuid for filenames when writing datasets with pyarrow.parquet?

Tags: io, parquet, pyarrow

Say I have a pandas DataFrame `df` that I would like to store on disk as dataset using pyarrow parquet, I would do this:
`table  = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df)
pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset(table, root_path=some_path, partition_cols=['a',])`

On disk the dataset would look like something like this:
some_path
├── a=1
____├── 4498704937d84fe5abebb3f06515ab2d.parquet
├── a=2
____├── 8bcfaed8986c4bdba587aaaee532370c.parquet

Q: Is it possible for me to override the auto-assignment of the long UUID as filename somehow during the **dataset** writing? My purpose is to be able to overwrite the dataset on disk when I have a new version of `df`. Currently if I try to write the dataset again, another new uniquely named [UUID].parquet file will be placed next to the old one, with the same, redundant data.

Comment: Can you open a JIRA issue with your feature request?

Comment: @WesMcKinney Thanks for the advice. Just opened one [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3538)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who's also interested in the development of this issue, it is solved as of `pyarrow` version 0.15.0, with great thanks to the open source community (Jira issue [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3538)).

Following the example used in the question:

```py
pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset(table, 
                                 some_path, 
                                 ['a',],
                                 partition_filename_cb=lambda x:'-'.join(x)+'.parquet')
```

would produce a saved dataset like this:

```sh
├── a=1
    ├── 1.parquet
├── a=2
    ├── 2.parquet
```

Comment: how would you do a hard-coded name?  I tried `partition_filename_cb='cdid-776.parquet',`, but I got a `'str' object is not callable`. Thanks.

Comment: @mbourgon you will need to use a Callable. Try `partition_filename_cb=lambda x: 'cdid-776.parquet'`.